# How can I use C# predefined get and set with a private field?

Tags: c#

Usually I would build my field like this:

```
private string name;

public void setName(string name){

    this.name = name;
}

public string getName(){

    return name
}
```

that works perfectly when doing this: `string myString = object.getName()` or `object.setName("Alex")`.

However, I thought I might give the inbuilt C# functions a try.

So I did this:

```
private string name { get; set; }
```

however, that won't work at all. When I try to access the field with `object.name`, I can't even access it due to private restriction.

Did I misunderstand something about these predefined get/sets?

If I had to mark every field as public, why should I even use getters or setters? I could access the field like in the snippet above without get and set?

Comment: You might want to [read up on restricting accessibility to properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx)

Comment: The aim of those properties is that you won´t need any `get/set`-emthods as the property itself implicitly creates them for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up *way* too many things - you might want to read a book on C#, really. It usually takes some time to get rid of some of the preconceptions from your old programming language - but you really do want to do that; even Java and C# are incredibly different when you go beyond the surface appearance.

First, nothing is forcing you to use auto-properties. If you want to use properties while keeping your manual backing fields, you can simply use this:

```
private string name;
public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
```

If you *do* want to use auto-properties, you have to understand that the backing field is hidden - you're only declaring the property; and you want that property to be public (though you can also use accessibility modifiers on the individual get/set "methods", e.g. `private set`). But the field is *never* accessible - it's "always" behind the property.

To mirror your original code, this is what you want:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Only if you ever need to move away from using auto-properties (that is, you need to add some logic to either the getter or the setter), you will have to reintroduce the manual backing field, and stop using auto-properties - see the first code sample in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Did I misunderstand something about these predefined get/sets?

Yes, you did. The property itself has to be `public`. If you're using *auto-properties*, then you can't do any validation since the backing field is compiler generated. If you want to actually do something with the value before, you can use a property with a *backing field*:

```
private string name;
public string Name 
{
    get { return name; }
    set 
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            throw new ArgumentException("name cannot be null");
        name = value
    }
}
```

Because this:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Generated a backing field like this:

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never), CompilerGenerated]
private string <Name>k__BackingField;
public string Name
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    get
    {
        return this.<Name>k__BackingField;
    }
    [CompilerGenerated]
    set
    {
        this.<Name>k__BackingField = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

That compiles down to a private field with an unspeakable name, and a public property. That public property has a public get method and a public set method.

Seems to be exactly what you want.

Alternatively, use

```
public string Name { get; private set; }
```

Your get method will be public as before, but the set method will be private then.

As of C# 6 (Visual Studio 2015), you can even do

```
public string Name { get; }
```

In that case, there is no set method, not even a private one, but you can assign to the underlying field through the property in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> Did I misunderstand something about these predefined get/sets?

Yes, a bit.

> If I had to mark every field as public, why should I even use getters or setters? I could access the field like in the snippet above without get and set?

This is the part that you're missing. The syntax you are talking about it called an *auto-implemented property*. That is, when you write:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

the C# compiler *generates* a private field, getter, and setter behind the scenes for you. You can see them if you look at the metadata for your class, and get access to them via reflection. They have the exact same names as the getter or setter you would write yourself (typically `get_Name` and `set_Name`). The only difference is, you didn't have to write them.

The reason to do this is because *most* getter/setter pairs only exist to add a layer of abstraction over a private field, and consist of a single `return name` or `name = value` line of code. If that's all you want, you may as well let the compiler write it for you.

However, if you ever needed something more complex, you can manually implement the getter and setter yourself, and *callers won't know the difference*. In other words, if you change:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

to

```
private string name;
public string Name 
{ 
    get 
    {
      return name; 
    } 
    set
    { 
      name = value; 
      RecalculateSomeStuff(); 
    }
}
```

then the metadata for your class is *identical*. Anyone using your class does not have to even be recompiled to pick up the new setter, because as far as the callers are concerned, they're still called `set_Name` directly.

Answer (score 0):

What the others want to tell you is that you should deferentiate between fields (privates) and properties (public)  (is not a rule but a convention)

```
private string name;

public string Name{ get; set;}

// you can acces to the property:
var objectName = YourObject.Name 

// and set the value of your property:
YourObject.Name = "whatever"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the equivalent of your code is

```
private string _name;
public string Name 
{ 
    get {return _name;}
    set { _name = value; } 
}
```

OR simply

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

To define the accessibility level of the "Name" field, you put the access modifiers (public, protected, etc.) before get or set

Example

```
//Read only properties
public string Name 
{ 
    get {return _name;}
    private set { _name = value; } 
}
```

To have more details and see difference between public fieal and public property see [Difference between Auto - Implemented Properties and normal public member](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d479ffff-41da-40fe-9274-62a211ef3edd/difference-between-auto-implemented-properties-and-normal-public-member-variables?forum=csharplanguage)

PS : 
To write this in Visual studio you can use snippet, type **prop** keyword then tab key or **propfull** and press tab key. press tab key our shift+tab to navigate between highlighted fields

[image: snippet for propertie]